How to find the resultant speed component, and finding the angle in which the trajectory had hit the ground?
When having a trajectory traveling over a projectile, both the vertical and horizontal velocity components must be obtained in order to calculate the resultant velocity.
The question is: Why the Pythagorean formula is used in order to obtain the resultant component, through
$$v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$$
For what purpose is the pythagorean theory used although this context has nothing to do with trigs and triangular equations.
Second, when aiming to obtain the angle in which the trajectory hit the ground, the $\arctan()$ notation is used;
$$θ = \arctan(v_y/v_x)$$
Again, why the arctan() function is used in order to determine the theta although the whole process has nothing to do with trigs.
If these steps are somehow a consequence of the process of resolving vector, can anyone explain the whole process and the point of suing such functions in such problems.


For what purpose is the Pythagorean theory used
although this context has nothing to do with trigs and triangular equations.

This context does have to do with right triangles and trigonometry.
Consider this right triangle with the three sides $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v$
and the angle $\theta$ (between $v_x$ and $v$).

Apply the Pythagorean theorem to it. You get
$$v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$$ or
$$v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$$

Second, when aiming to obtain the angle in which the
trajectory hit the ground, the arctan() notation is used;

Consider this triangle again. Apply the geometric definition
of the tangent function to the angle $\theta$. You get
$$\tan\theta=\frac{v_y}{v_x}$$ or
$$\theta=\arctan\frac{v_y}{v_x}$$

Any velocity can be considered to be the vector sum of two component velocities. For a projectile it is convenient to resolve the velocity into a horizontal component ($v_x$) which can be considered to be constant if air resistance is ignored and a vertical component ($v_y$) that is constantly changing due to the acceleration of gravity. At any instant we can find an instantaneous vertical component. In the diagram below, the horizontal component is the HF segment and the vertical component is the HE segment.

From the diagram it is easy to see that the FG segment is the same length as the HE segment and that the points H,F and G form a right angel triangle. It therefore follows that v can be found using the Pythagoras equation from  $v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$
The tangent of an angle is (opp)/(adj) and so $(FG)/(HF) = F_y/f_x = \tan(\angle (FHG))$ and so the angle defined by FHG is equal to $atan(F_y/F_x)$.
